What derailleur hanger is this and what is actually compatible and what needs changing?
Bought this bike second hand. Obviously these are not stock components here, the rear derailleur should not be direct mount. I can not seem to find the specifications for the hangar anywhere. Also I can not tell if instead of the bolt, whether i can just replace these with quick release axels.
Thanks

Could you provide the brand and model of the bike frame, and approximate age ?

Derailleur hangers come in a bewildering range - literally hundreds of different incompatible designs.
And you don't even have the original to compare with pictures, making this extra tough.
Your best options are to

Identify your bike brand and model, then work backward to a hanger.  Start here  https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hanger-tech-help

Exhaustively look at charts and see what might work , starting with a search for derailleur hanger


Clearly the current setup is incorrect, and is likely leading to poor shifting.
Also, be prepared for price shock.  A hanger may cost as much as a used bike.
